# Substage - Making templates MS StyleCop compliant

Tags: c#, subsonic, substage

I have a good sized hobby project, around 66K LOC, over at http://www.wheelmud.net  Recently, a team member got the bulk of the code MS StyleCop compliant. The only thing left is our data layer. As you can imagine, this gets regenerated fairly often, as we are still in the early stages of development.

I tried modifying the aspx templates, but I saw quite a few things that I need fixed. The first thing I saw was that the using statements were on top of the namespace declaration. Is there any way to modify this behavior through the templates, or do I need to take a chainsaw to SubStage's code?

I don't mind changing the source, but I wanted to ask first before I jump in. I have done this before for other projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to roll all of the existing templates into T4 to avoid future template issues. We'll still support the old stuff - but using T4 to do this will really help situations like yours

Comment: I know that you are working on v3. Will this be done for v2.2?

Thanks Rob, you're doing an awesome job!

Answer (score 0):

In version 2.2, a patch was added to add a  tag to the top of generated files so they would be ignored by StyleCop. [See this issue](http://code.google.com/p/subsonicproject/issues/detail?id=40).

Comment: The other way of doing this is to store a Settings.StyleCop file in the same folder as the code. I actually wanted to make the templates compliant, not have them skipped altogether. Thanks anyways.